# No results in query SPARQL

Tags: rdf, sparql, jena

I am using JENA and I am making some simple queries for learning purposes. One of them is:

```sql
PREFIX uni:<http://www.university.fake/university#>
PREFIX rdf:<http://www.w3.org/1999/02/22-rdf-syntax-ns#>
PREFIX rdfs:<http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#>

SELECT ?person
WHERE {
    ?person rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf <uni:Person>.
    ?person uni:has_name ?name.
    ?person uni:member_of ?dep.
    ?dep uni:dep_city "Patras".
}
```

Without the 4th triple the rest do produce results if `?dep` of the 3rd one is replaced with a quoted value. However, when adding the 4th triple, there are no results. The triple itself does produce results in its own query, so I don't think there is any problem there.

Some of the RDF data:

```xml
<rdf:Property rdf:about="uni:member_of">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="uni:Person"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="uni:Department"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Property rdf:about="uni:dep_city">
    <rdfs:domain rdf:resource="uni:Department"/>
    <rdfs:range rdf:resource="uni:Literal"/>
</rdf:Property>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="uni:dep1">
    <uni:dep_name>CEID</uni:dep_name>
    <uni:dep_city>Patras</uni:dep_city>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="uni:prof2">
    <uni:has_name>Bob Ross</uni:has_name>
    <uni:has_phone>6981234566</uni:has_phone>
    <uni:has_age>52</uni:has_age>
    <uni:member_of>CEID</uni:member_of>
    <uni:teaches>Painting</uni:teaches>
    <rdf:type rdf:resource="uni:Professor"/>
</rdf:Description>
```

Comment: So `?dep uni:dep_city "Patras"` works? Try working backwards from there, that is try `?person uni:member_of ?dep. ?dep uni:dep_city "Patras"` etc.

Comment: Also, provide data if possible. Hard to diagnose without data.

Comment: Yes, it works. The second query you suggest doesn't work though, and that's probably where the problem is. An example of the RDF data is:
`<rdf:Description rdf:about="uni:prof2">
 <uni:has_name>Bob Ross</uni:has_name>
 <uni:has_phone>6981234566</uni:has_phone>
 <uni:has_age>52</uni:has_age>
 <uni:member_of>CEID</uni:member_of>
 <uni:teaches>Painting</uni:teaches>
 <rdf:type rdf:resource="uni:Professor"/>
</rdf:Description>
<rdf:Description rdf:about="uni:dep1">
 <uni:dep_name>CEID</uni:dep_name>
 <uni:dep_city>Patras</uni:dep_city>
</rdf:Description>`

Answer (score 4):

Aha, so given the data it seems like, depending on one's perspective, either the query is wrong or the data is badly modelled.

As it stands `?person uni:member_of ?dep` isn't going to work. You could join on `uni:dep_name` (assuming these are unique keys).

```
?person uni:member_of ?dep_name .
?dep uni:dep_name ?dep_name ;
     uni:dep_city "Patras" .
```

However I think the data really ought to be corrected to make (in turtle syntax) `uni:prof2 uni:member_of uni:dep1`.

Indeed you have worse issues with your data, which aren't uncommon for beginners or even experienced people using rdf/xml.

```
<rdf:Description rdf:about="uni:member_of">
   ...
```

This *doesn't* mean what you think it means. `rdf:about` and `rdf:resource` attributes take full URLs, not the abbreviated forms. You should use `rdf:about="http://example.com/namespace/university#member_of"`, or whatever the URL of the uni namespace is.

This mistake is why you have:

```
?person rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf <uni:Person>
```

rather than:

```
?person rdf:type/rdfs:subClassOf uni:Person
```

In SPARQL and turtle `<uni:Person>` matches the URL 'uni:Person' (which doesn't exist), whereas 'uni:Person' is an abbreviated URL which will be expanded using the uni prefix.

When you're learning I'd strongly advise avoiding rdf/xml. Turtle is much easier to read and write, and matches the SPARQL syntax (minus variables) to a great extent.

Comment: Thanks for the tips! I will try to get into Turtle some time, but for the moment I'm still in SPARQL basics. It turns out that my data was badly modeleted indeed, because I mistakenly thought that the inference engine would recognise same literals from different resources if the schema appointed them to those types.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently the mistake was in `<uni:member_of>CEID</uni:member_of>`, which should have been a reference to another resource. The correct one is `<uni:member_of rdf:resource="uni:dep1"/>`